# Groups taking so long.... finally timedout?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have around 300,000 users in the site collection and around 250 groups in the same site collection. When I am trying to open any group to get users in it. It is taking so long and finally it is showing "Request time out". another than that.... site collection is working fine.

How can open groups normally with out delay?

Comment: You mean through the web interface??

Comment: what is the content database size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to try to increase the default execution timeout in the shared web.config under the `\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`

By default, it's 6 minutes (360s), you can try to increase it to 20 minutes

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
</system.web>
```

That will allow more time for the working process to execute its job. It will thus not solve your question "opening without delay" but it will hopefully avoid the dreaded "request has timed out"

I guess a little peak through Reflector might see something dirty in the way the UI is managing / retrieving the group users... A custom, code improved, administration page that will replace the built-in group management might thus be a possible solution.